# SQL check if date is N days back from last month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to check the edit of invoices (in a table lets say Invoices) based on dateIssued.

(SQL Server 2008 R2)

The idea is that last month invoice data can be altered until the Nth day of the current month. After that, only current month invoices can be altered. In no way Invoices can be altered 2 months and so back.

Example. Lets say N = 20 days

This means that I can alter November invoices until 20 of December. At 21 of December I can alter only December invoices.

I hope I am descriptive enough :(

```
SELECT invoiceNo, dateIssued FROM Invoices;

invoiceNo dateIssued
001       2016-10-30 00:00:00.000
002       2016-12-01 00:00:00.000
003       2016-11-03 00:00:00.000
004       2016-11-24 00:00:00.000
005       2016-09-09 00:00:00.000
```

I cannot build an elegant algorithm that can select from the table the correct-for-edit-invoices depending on the date the system is.

Thanx

Comment: What do you want a query to do?  Sample data *and* desired results would be helpful.

Comment: A simple select from the table that will retrieve which invoices can be altered, based on system date and the above requested filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the invoices that can be modified today, then something like this:

```
select i.*
from invoices i
where year(dateissued) * 12 + month(dateissued) = year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate()) or
      (day(getdate()) <= @n and
       year(dateissued) * 12 + month(dateissued) = year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate()) - 1
      ) ;
```

The funky expression using year * 12 + month is just getting the number of months since time zero.  It is convenient for getting current and last month.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Invoices AS TABLE (InvoiceNo INT, dateIssues DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Invoices VALUES
(1,'2016-10-30 00:00:00.000')
,(2,'2016-12-01 00:00:00.000')
,(3,'2016-11-03 00:00:00.000')
,(4,'2016-11-24 00:00:00.000')
,(5,'2016-09-09 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @N INT = 20

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Invoices
WHERE
    dateIssues >=
    CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) < @N
       THEN DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1 - DAY(GETDATE()),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) --beginning of last month
       ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1 - DAY(GETDATE()),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))  --beginning of this month
    END
```

Comment: Looks like this solution would return invoices for future months as well, which the question implies is not the intention: "After that, **only current month invoices** can be altered.".

Comment: @3N1GM4 presumably an invoice isn't "issued" in the future from the use of past tense dateIssued which would mean that invoices beyond the current month wouldn't exist in the dataset. But should that be the case I wouldn't see any business reason they would not be able to be changed if one is able to change an invoice until n (20) days into a later month and when it is "finalized". Wouldn't a future invoice then implicitly allowed to be changed?

Comment: Fair enough [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5510627/matt), and I do agree with you for what it's worth, just thought it would be worth pointing out in case [PanosPlat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/597243/panosplat) wanted to clarify their question.

Comment: @3N1GM4 your comment made me think twice. It's not a bad thing to discuss as it helps the OP understand nuances of different solutions which there are always a few when discussing date/datetime. Both were good and reasonable solutions given OPs terminology so I understand the comment just not the downvote but who knows maybe that was from someone else. Cheers

Comment: I agree Matt, the downvote was due to the OP specifically saying "I can alter **only** December invoices." in their example, but I will admit that it seems unlikely this was their true intention (and regardless this is an unlikely edge case we are discussing). Unfortunately it's too late for me to retract my downvote now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @LastDayForEditingPreviousMonth INT = 20

-- Return only invoices for the current month, of those for last month if the @LastDayForEditingPreviousMonth day has not been passed
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE (     DATEPART(YEAR,dateissued) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) 
        AND DATEPART(MONTH,dateissued) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
      ) -- Invoices for this month
OR (    DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()) <= @LastDayForEditingPreviousMonth
    AND DATEPART(YEAR,dateissued) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(MONTH,dateissued) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) - 1
) -- Invoices from last month (if eligible)
```

Comment: Would not be able to alter invoices for "next" month if they existed ahead of time. Plus the date calculations on the column will not perform as well as a straight comparison as an index would not be able to be used.

Comment: As discussed in the comments on your answer [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5510627/matt), it's unclear from the question which behaviour is desired if there are invoices with an `dateIssued` value in a future month, but you are obviously right that if they could exist and were desired in the results, my solution will not return them, as conversely your solution **would** return them even if they were not wanted.